# onclick button does not do anything; javascript function not called

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, identity

I am trying to do a login page with a database but my button does not perform any action when clicked even though it should bring me tomy next page(index2.html). Nothing shows even in the console so i do not know what is wrong with it.

Javascript code

```
var response ="";
  function plogin(){
  var credentials = new Object();

  credentials.username= document.getElementById("user").value;
  credentials.password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open("POST","/userlogin", true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
  request.onload=function(){

  response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  document.getElementById("loginform").style.display="none";
  if (response.message =="1"){
     window.location = "index2.html?username=" + credentials.username;}
  else{
     document.getElementById("msg").textContent = response.message;}
```

Login Form

```
<form id = "loginform" onclick="plogin()"> 
        <label style="color: white;">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" style="border-style: solid; border-width:5px; border-color: slategrey;" placeholder="Jon" id="user" name="username">
        <br>
        <label style="color: white;">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" style="border-style: solid; border-width:5px; border-color: slategrey;" id="password" name="password">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button"  class = "btn btn-secondary" value="Login">
      </form>
```

both codes are in the same html page

userlogin code(js) works in Postman

````
userlogin(request, respond){
        var username = request.body.username;
        var password = request.body.password;
        var msg="";

        var sql = "SELECT user.password FROM restaurant_review.user WHERE username = ?";

        db.query(sql, [username], function(error,result){
            if(error){
                throw error;
            }
            else{
                if(result.length > 0){
                    if(password == result[0].password){
                        msg ="1";
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                    else{
                        msg = "FAIL";
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    msg = "USER NOT FOUND";
                    console.log(msg);
                }
                respond.json(prepareMessage(msg));
            }
        });
   ```we
````

Comment: Just change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`. Buttons doesn't have a default behaviour: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button

Comment: First of all, form can't have onClick method, it should be submit or either change the input button to submit button or add onClick method on your input button. 
One more thing your function name is also different. plogin and userlogin. Make sure it is the function that you want to bind with the button.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya The button doesn't have to be a submit button. He trigger an onClick() event on the button he is currently using and then submit the form from JavaScript.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo, can you please read once more what I've written. ` either change the input button to submit button or add onClick method on your input button`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in HTML `<button type="submit">...</button>` instead of `<input type="button"  class = "btn btn-secondary" value="Login">`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is triggering because you're not submitting your form. You have some options. If you use a submit button with the input type being equal to "submit", your form will submit. If you want to continue using an input type of "button", you can use the "onclick" method to trigger your function:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Submit">
```

In JavaScript you can add an event listener to the button that waits for a click event. I will use jQuery in this basic example:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    //Enter the request to the server within your callback function.
});
```

Within your event listener for a click event the second argument passed to it is something known as a "callback function". You can implement the code for your request within a callback function. If you want to use pure JavaScript it would like something like this:

```
var btn = Document.getElementByClassName('btn');
btn.onclick = function() { /*your programming logic*/ };
```